# SharpMap overlay MapInfo on Bing/Google

Tags: c#, google-maps, bing-maps, sharpmap

I want to use SharpMap to overlay a MapInfo tab file onto Google or Bing.

I have it working pretty much at the moment however the co-ordinates that Bing/Google show are in correct so my MapInfo file doesn't make any sense to the region its being overlaid on. I think I need to transform the MapInfo coordinates to the Bing/Google type but I'm not entirely sure how to do this or if this is the correct thing.

I'm using SharpMap 0.9

This is my code so far

```
myMap = new Map(new Size((int)imgMap.Width.Value, (int)imgMap.Height.Value));

var ogrProvider = new Ogr(@"C:\test.tab");

var layer = new VectorLayer("test");
layer.DataSource = ogrProvider;

var layerbing = new TileLayer(new BingTileSource(BingRequest.UrlBing, "", BingMapType.Aerial), "TileLayer");
//var layergoogle = new TileLayer(new GoogleTileSource(GoogleMapType.GoogleMap), "googlemaps");

myMap.Layers.Add(layerbing);
// myMap.Layers.Add(layergoogle);

myMap.Layers.Add(layer);
myMap.ZoomToBox(layer.Envelope);
```

When I run it up the "layer" has a SRID of 7 and the "layerbing" has a SRID of -1, I think this might be the issue and I need to transform the co-ordinates, but I'm not sure how to transform them and from/to what I need to.

Comment: I have figured out that bing uses the co-ordinates system "EPSG:3785" and my layer uses the system "EPSG:28356", still not sure how to convert though

Comment: You should be able to transform the layer you are adding

Comment: I can transform it now, but it is about 200km out of where it should be....http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/discussions/259181

Comment: You're not transforming it correctly then Daniel.  Or, is the original data ok?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to use BruTile 0.7.4 for the Bing maps to work correctly (there was a bug in the 0.7.3).
0.7.4 is newly released on NuGet

The you can do like this..

```
SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer vLay = new SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer("Name of layer", provider);

ICoordinateTransformationFactory ctFact = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.CoordinateTransformationFactory();
vLay.CoordinateTransformation = 
   ctFact.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(getGDA94(csFact), GetEPSG900913(csFact));
vLay.ReverseCoordinateTransformation = 
ctFact.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(GetEPSG900913(csFact), getGDA94(csFact));
```

And the helper methods

```
        ICoordinateSystem getGDA94(ICoordinateSystemFactory csFact)
        {
            return csFact.CreateFromWkt("PROJCS[\"GDA94 / MGA zone 56\",GEOGCS[\"GDA94\",DATUM[\"D_GDA_1994\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",153],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",500000],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",10000000],UNIT[\"Meter\",1]]");
        }

        private IProjectedCoordinateSystem GetEPSG900913(ICoordinateSystemFactory csFact)
        {
            List<GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.ProjectionParameter> parameters = new List<GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.ProjectionParameter>();

            parameters.Add(new GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.ProjectionParameter("semi_major", 6378137.0));
            parameters.Add(new GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.ProjectionParameter("semi_minor", 6378137.0));
            parameters.Add(new GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.ProjectionParameter("latitude_of_origin", 0.0));
            parameters.Add(new GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.ProjectionParameter("central_meridian", 0.0));
            parameters.Add(new GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.ProjectionParameter("scale_factor", 1.0));
            parameters.Add(new GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.ProjectionParameter("false_easting", 0.0));
            parameters.Add(new GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.ProjectionParameter("false_northing", 0.0));

            GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.IProjection projection = csFact.CreateProjection("Google Mercator", "mercator_1sp", parameters);
            GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.IGeographicCoordinateSystem wgs84 = csFact.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem(
                "WGS 84", ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.AngularUnit.Degrees,
                ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.HorizontalDatum.WGS84,
                ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.PrimeMeridian.Greenwich,
                new GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.AxisInfo("north", GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.AxisOrientationEnum.North),
                new GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.AxisInfo("east", GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.AxisOrientationEnum.East)
            );

            GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.IProjectedCoordinateSystem epsg900913 = csFact.CreateProjectedCoordinateSystem("Google Mercator", wgs84, projection,
                ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.LinearUnit.Metre, new GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.AxisInfo("East", GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.AxisOrientationEnum.East),
                new GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.AxisInfo("North", GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.AxisOrientationEnum.North)
            );

            return epsg900913;
        }
```